# How to mmap() 64-bit address into 32-bit process?

Tags: c, mmap

I'm trying to map device memory residing on 64-bit address into 32-bit process on 64-bit OS.
I'm using the following lines

```
baseaddr = addr & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY | O_SYNC);
base_ptr = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, baseaddr);
```

baseaddr is uint64_t and is higher than 4GB.

and I compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.
When I run the program it returns `EINVAL`.
It worked before without the `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, but it'd only use the lower 32-bits of baseaddr - that I conclude by output of pmap -d showing the lower 32-bits of my desired address.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How could a 32bit process cope with 64bit addresses? Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: Check if you have the [`mmap64`](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/mmap.3.asp) function.

Comment: Just to check: What is the actual value of `baseaddr`?

Comment: @ctx I have checked that in gdb it is 0x3807cd007000 before I call mmap().

Comment: @Pyjong Are there any suspicious messages in the kernel log after the call fails?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've tried using mmap64, the compiler gives me warning it is implicit declaration, but it compiles and the symbol then appears in readelf --syms, but it still returns EINVAL.

Comment: Yes, the `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` should automatically redirect the call to `mmap()` to `mmap64()`

Comment: @Ctx I don't think there anything suspicious in output of dmesg. At least there is nothing recent to me running the code.

Comment: oohhhh.. so stepping through assembly of mmap64.S it would do    movl OFFLO(%esp), %edx    movl OFFHI(%esp), %ecx   and then jump to einval with /* mmap2 takes the offset in pages.  */ I guess I have to shift the address right then.

Comment: @Pyjong You shouldn't use `mmap64` directly. SDefining `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` should take care of that. If mmap returns `INVAL`, check if `addr`, `length` and `offset` parameters are all page-aligned. Check the man page for all reasons why it could return `EINVAL`.

Comment: Ok, here's an explanation: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap2.2.html so basically my address is too high.

Comment: what type are the `addr` and `baseaddr` variables? (and btw, _forget_ about `mmap64` or `mmap2` -- `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` should define `mmap` -> `mmap64`, and make `off_t` 64bits).

Comment: @Pyjong That's not an explanation.  What does your code emit if you try something like `printf( "sizeof( off_t ) = %d\n", ( int ) sizeof( off_t ) );`?  It should output 8.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ah cmon, comment #4, yes I have made sure the whole value gets in. I've stepped it through gdb all the way to that shrdl instruction that shifts the high part into lower dword by 12, then it checks the higher dword for zeroness and since it's not zero it returns EINVAL. (because that means the higher part was larger than 2^44) now it must be clear

Comment: That 2^44 limit is for 32-bit `off_t`.  Note the comment in [mmap64.c](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap64.c.html):    *For archictures **with 32 bits off_t** and page size of 4096 it would be 1^44.*  But given `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, `off_t` should be 64 bits.  Something is broken, you don't know what, so you need to examine and verify all your assumptions here - and it's really easy to check the size of `off_t`.  Given your *It worked before*, did somebody munge a header file somewhere?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm at older glibc 2.18 (just please read the file in the answer bellow), parameter passing works fine. It might work if I do the syscall on my own though. The syscall probably does not have this limitation.

Comment: @Jens The `/dev/mem` special file maps memory addresses to file offsets. A 32-bit process can use 64-bit file offsets, so using `/dev/mem` 64-bit file offsets mapped to 32-bit memory addresses, it can cope with 64-bit addresses. There are a lot of potential gotchas though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my final solution was to add mixed 32/64 assembly code that switches to long mode, loads long registers with desired values and then syscalls without any sort of wrapper and switches back to protected. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `mmap64` here.  The address has to be mapped into an area that a 32-bit process can use.  However, I *strongly* advise that you get a true 64-bit version of this application.  You're heading down a rabbit-hole here and there's a lot of rabbit-poo in that hole, if you catch my drift ...

Comment: I would use 64-bit compiler if I could.

Comment: @Pyjong why? Both GCC and Clang can compile to 32 and 64-bit executables

Comment: @phuclv I have to comply to my workspace's build system :/ but yeah otherwise I would agree.

Comment: 32- or 64-bit application shouldn't matter with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` as then `off_t` would be 64 bits.